# cal:Message.Attach issues with Telerik WPF ReportViewer

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro, telerik-reporting

Has anyone tried to cal:Message.Attach to the Telerik WPF ReportViewer events?

Is there any reason I should not be able to use Caliburn.Micro Message.Attach for the WPF ReportView PrintEnd event to exchange between the View and ViewModel? ReportView is a FrameworkElement. I have binding working nicely for the ReportSource

```
.NET 4.5 
Telerik.ReportViewer.Wpf 9.0.15.225 
Caliburn.Micro 2.0.2.0
```

I get the following when attempting this:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll
The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
```

WPF User Control

```
<tr:ReportViewer Name="reportViewer"
                 ViewMode="PrintPreview"
                 ZoomMode="FullPage"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                 ReportSource="{Binding Path=ReportSource}" 
                 cal:Message.Attach="[PrintEnd]=[OnPrintEnded()]"
                 />
```

ViewModel (Caliburn.Micro Screen)

```
public void OnPrintEnded()
{
    // 
}
```

It seems as though CM is attaching the event, but the message is being pushed from a different thread than what my VM instance is on. I created a very light project with just the minimal Caliburn.Micro.Start and a single reportviewer and empty report class within the ShellView.xaml to isolate the issue, but get the exact same results.

I have a workaround devised, but would like to see if this can be resolved

Answer (score 0):

You should try this way :

```
cal:Message.Attach="[Event PrintEnd] = [Action OnPrintEnded]"
```

For more informations, see documentation about Caliburn.Micro actions : [Caliburn.Micro actions](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Actions)

Comment: Thanks, I had tried that, but it had no impact. I can attach PrintBegin, ExportBegin, and ExportEnd (using either style) with no issue, however PrintEnd specifically throws this exception. Maybe has to do with how the Telerik ReportViewer is firing the event.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik support confirmed the event was being published from a different thread and have logged the issue for corrective action.